# Azure function which just inserts a record into a snowflake table is working fine but failing because of timeout issue sometime

Tags: azure-functions, timeout

I have an Azure function that inserts a record into a snowflake table. The function is working fine but sometimes the function is failing because of a timeout issue. The below work code is handled in the host.json file. The application insight logs say that it is a timeout error. Though the retry option is given as 3. The function fails again.

"extensions": {
"concurrency": {
"dynamicConcurrencyEnabled": true,
"snapshotPersistenceEnabled": true
}
}
}

Any solution to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Timeout on the back end trying to reach an external resource. Outside of the external resource not accepting the connection SNAT port exhaustion is the most common reason for these time out failures. This article does a great job of describing SNAT https://4lowtherabbit.github.io/blogs/2019/10/SNAT/

you can also check if this is an issue using the Diagnose and Solve problems blade in the Azure portal
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-intermittent-outbound-connection-errors#:~:text=To%20find%20SNAT%20port%20allocation%20information%2C%20follow%20the,to%20keep%20it%20below%20128.%20...%20See%20More.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-intermittent-outbound-connection-errors#:%7E:text=To%20find%20SNAT%20port%20allocation%20information%2C%20follow%20the,to%20keep%20it%20below%20128.%20...%20See%20More.)

Answer (score 0):

I assume your goal is to get rid of timeout? If yes than this table might help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale

You can control the timeout by adding this entry to your job configuration in azure:

Key: *AzureFunctionsJobHost__functionTimeout*

Value: *valueInMinutes*

If you wonna go unlimited just put '-1' in value.